# C# XML RPC Client

Tags: c#, client, xml-rpc

I'm working on an application that will need to communicate with an XMLRPC server.
Currently I'm using CookComputing's library from xml-rpc.net

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, fairly new to C#.
I'm trying to invoke the RPC call "main.tx" which when recieived by the server should enable the transmit mode/function of the server software I want to communicate with.

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;

namespace xmlrpc
{
    [XmlRpcUrl("localhost:7362")]
    public interface HelloWorld : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("main.tx")]
        String HelloWorld();
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HelloWorld proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<HelloWorld>();
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.HelloWorld());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize there was more to the exception than I was seeing on the tooltip.
I simply had to specify the address with 'http://'

Everything is working now, below is the solution.

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;

namespace xmlrpc
{
    [XmlRpcUrl("http://localhost:7362")]
    public interface FlRPC : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("main.tx")]
        String MainTx();
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FlRPC proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<FlRPC>();
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.MainTx());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```